# How to transpose SQL table partially without aggregates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need you guys' expert advice on partially transposing this MS SQL Table:

```
| Term | Listening | Reading | Speaking | Writing |
| AC1  | 12        | 15      | 18       | 13      |
| AC2  | 17        | 14      | 9        | 12      |
```

into this:

```
| Term | Comp      | Score |
| AC1  | Listening | 12    |
| AC1  | Reading   | 15    |
| AC1  | Speaking  | 18    |
| AC1  | Writing   | 13    |
| AC2  | Listening | 17    |
| AC2  | Reading   | 14    |
| AC2  | Speaking  | 9     |
| AC2  | Writing   | 12    |
```

Appreciate if you can give advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are thousand example of Pivot & UnPivot , Google for Them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is [**`UNPIVOT`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```sql
SELECT Term, Comp, Score
FROM mytable
UNPIVOT
   (Score FOR Comp IN 
      ([Listening], [Reading], [Speaking], [Writing])
)AS unpvt;
```

Comment: Thanks, Giorgos Betsos. This is awesome!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT term,comp,trems
FROM 
   (SELECT *
   FROM #b) p
UNPIVOT
   (trems FOR comp IN 
      (Listening, Reading, Speaking, Writing)
)AS unpvt;
GO
```

output

```
term    comp    trems
AC1 Listening   12
AC1 Reading     15
AC1 Speaking    18
AC1 Writing     13
AC2 Listening   17
AC2 Reading     14
AC2 Speaking    9
AC2 Writing     12
```

or

```
 SELECT
    term,comp,trems
    FROM #b
    CROSS APPLY (
          Values
             ('Listening' , Listening),
             ('Reading' , Reading),
             ('Speaking', Speaking) ,
             ('Writing', Writing)
      ) as CA (comp, trems)

   output


term    comp    trems
AC1 Listening   12
AC1 Reading     15
AC1 Speaking    18
AC1 Writing     13
AC2 Listening   17
AC2 Reading     14
AC2 Speaking    9
AC2 Writing     12
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use **[`UNPIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** in order to translate your columns into rows.

```
SELECT
    UNPVTBL.Term
    , UNPVTBL.Comp
    , UNPVTBL.Score
FROM Table
UNPIVOT
(Score FOR Comp IN (Listening, Reading, Speaking, Writing) ) UNPVTBL
ORDER BY UNPVTBL.Term
```