# How to partially transpose a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to create a table with a lists of contacts (ClientCode, Telephone, Name) from a table structured like this:

| ClientCode | Telephone1 | Name1 | Telephone2 | Name2 | Telephone3 | Name3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 55555 | John M. | 79879 | Frank | 897987 | Paul |
| 9884 | 84416 | Richard | 88416 | Helen | 11594 | Katrin |

I need to group by ClientCode same persons that work at the same client.

Table expected:

| ClientCode | Telephone | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 55555 | John M. |
| 1234 | 79879 | Frank |
| 1234 | 897987 | Paul |
| 9884 | 84416 | Richard |
| 9884 | 88416 | Helen |
| 9884 | 1159 | Katrin |

I've tried the following solution (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41118393/how-to-transpose-sql-table-partially-without-aggregates) answer) but the output is not correct

```sql
SELECT UNPVTBL.CLIENTCODE, UNPVTBL.NAME
FROM (SELECT * FROM -ORIGIN_TABLE-) P
UNPIVOT
(NAME FOR CONTACTS IN
    (NAME1, NAME2, NAME3)
)UNPVTBL

UNION
SELECT UNPVTBL.CLIENTCODE, UNPVTBL.TELEPHONE
FROM (SELECT * FROM -ORIGIN_TABLE-) G
UNPIVOT
(TELEPHONE FOR TELEPH IN
(TELEPHONE1, TELEPHONE2, TELEPHONE3) 
)UNPVTBL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing it using the `UNION ALL` operator:

```
SELECT ClientCode, Telephone1 AS Telephone, Name1 AS Name FROM tab
UNION ALL
SELECT ClientCode, Telephone2 AS Telephone, Name2 AS Name FROM tab
UNION ALL
SELECT ClientCode, Telephone3 AS Telephone, Name3 AS Name FROM tab
```

Output:

| ClientCode | Telephone | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 55555 | John M. |
| 9884 | 84416 | Richard |
| 1234 | 79879 | Frank |
| 9884 | 88416 | Helen |
| 1234 | 897987 | Paul |
| 9884 | 11594 | Katrin |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/irbIan77).

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is VALUES unpivot:

```sql
select t.ClientCode,x.name, x.Telephone
from (
    VALUES  (1234, 55555, N'John M.', 79879, N'Frank', 897987, N'Paul')
    ,   (9884, 84416, N'Richard', 88416, N'Helen', 11594, N'Katrin')
) t (ClientCode,Telephone1,Name1,Telephone2,Name2,Telephone3,Name3)
cross apply (
    VALUES  (Telephone1, Name1)
    ,   (Telephone2, Name2)
    ,   (Telephone3, Name3)
    ) x (Telephone, Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Hopefully* this exercise is to fix you design; if it isn't, it should be.

As for the solution, a `VALUES` table construct seems to do this simply enough:

```sql
SELECT YT.ClientCode,
       V.Telephone,
       V.[Name]
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(Telephone1,Name1),
                       (Telephone2,Name2),
                       (Telephone3,Name3))V(Telephone,Name);
```